# ssh2 ssh2_connect() function not found

Tags: php, installation, litespeed, ssh2

So I have a class that I build that uses the ssh2 package in php. I have successfully set this up and used and tested this class on apache2 server. The server at work where this is going to be running is an instance of litespeed. I have scoured the web for a way to get ssh2 working with this litespeed server however I cannot for the life of me figure it out. I get ssh2_connect() function not found. If I go go /etc/php/... I can see that the ssh2.ini file exists. However I believe the active php instance is located /usr/local/lsws/lsphp74/7.4/etc/php/ where I do not see the ss2.ini located. Is there a way to get ssh2 installed in the directory that is being used by the server?  If I run ssh2_connect at the command prompt, it works just fine as it is most likely using the /etc/php instance of php.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct, `ssh2_connect()` is provided by a pecl extension. These are optional binary add-ons for php. I'd make a quick `phpinfo();` page and add it to the litespeed server so you can see what modules are active and where the config files php is using are actually located on disk.

The install guide can walk you through installing this pecl extension.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/ssh2.requirements.php

Another way to accomplish this is with a pure-php library that doesn't depend on special plug-ins. [phpseclib](https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib) fully implements the ssh protocol in pure php, taking advantage of libraries if they are present but it's able to function without them.

Comment: Just to be sure, is the process different for apache web servers? I got this same script working with out having to build anything I simply ran an apt-get install command and this worked to get the same issue resolved on an apache based server but not yielding the same results with this litespeed instance>

Comment: My guess is its not the server, its the package has different default things installed.
You'll even see differences between distros or control panel packages. that doesn't mean you can't install it yourself. The phpinfo() will show what's installed. Running it in both places (your working server and the not working one) will show you what's missing so you can install it.

Answer (score 1):

since you didn't mention what exactly is your server env

I would assume it's either OpenLiteSpeed image , or CyberPanel image

first of all , compile libssh2

```
wget https://libssh2.org/download/libssh2-1.10.0.tar.gz
tar vxzf libssh2-1.10.0.tar.gz
cd libssh2-1.10.0
./configure
make
make install
```

then compile the PHP extension

```
mkdir /usr/local/lsws/lsphp74/tmp
pecl channel-update pecl.php.net
/usr/local/lsws/lsphp74/bin/pear config-set temp_dir "/usr/local/lsws/lsphp74/tmp"
/usr/local/lsws/lsphp74/bin/pecl install https://pecl.php.net/get/ssh2-1.3.1.tgz
echo "extension=ssh2.so" > /usr/local/lsws/lsphp74/etc/php/7.4/mods-available/50-ssh2.ini
```

and finally , restart lsphp process to load new module

```
touch /usr/local/lsws/admin/tmp/.lsphp_restart.txt
```

or

```
killall lsphp
```

then verify by `phpinfo();` to make sure you see ssh2 loaded

Comment: Thank you for all that info. I make it through to the step /usr/local/lsws/lsphp74/bin/pear config-set temp_dir "/usr/local/lsws/lsphp74/tmp" but the bin/pear directory does not exist. Is there another package that needs to be installed for that directory path to exist?

Comment: I figured it out!  Your steps worked marvelously! The hair left on my head thanks you as well!

Comment: so everything was working and now it is like i never installed ssh2 at all.  Getting the same error that ssh2_connect not found?

Comment: So I followed your steps and it was working fine, now it will not work and I am getting the same error. I do see the line 50-ssh2.ini in the mods available file. Still wont load in to php.ini as when I run phpinfo(); I do not see that it is installed.

Comment: check if `ssh2.so` still exists somewhere in your /usr/local/lsws/lsphp74/

Comment: so now pear is not installed and when I try to install it it wants to update the php.ini file in etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini.  the php.ini that I am using is in /usr/local/lsws/lsphp74/etc/php/7.4/litespeed.  the current include path is, :/usr/local/lsws/lsphp74/bin//share/php and the current configured directory is :/usr/local/lsws/lsphp74/bin//share/php.

Comment: now trying to follow your instructions i get an error about phpize not found.

Comment: i dont see ssh2.so anywhere in /usr/local/lsws/lsphp74/.  It definitely was working just fine and then I was working on some front end stuff and when I tried to use it again, i go the error that it could not find the ssh2_connect function. I don't know why any of this happened and tried to follow the steps again and it still did not work. I even restored the server to an old image backup prior to any of that and go through the steps again and still failed. At this point I am completely lost

Comment: try recompile it again , and make sure no error output , then check ssh2.so file

Comment: Again thank you for are your help, when I run the make step I do get these warnings which I did not get when I originally ran the make step  warning: ignoring return value of ‘write’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]

Comment: how can I get this system to only work with the php version at the path /usr/local/lsws/lsphp74. I feel that there is like 5-6 places where there are php folders with php.ini files located in them. When I just recompiled and tried to install, this is the result, Build process completed successfully
Installing '/usr/lib/php/20190902/ssh2.so'
install ok: channel://pecl.php.net/ssh2-1.3.1
configuration option "php_ini" is not set to php.ini location
You should add "extension=ssh2.so" to php.ini
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: I also see this /usr/local/lsws/lsphp74/etc/php/7.4/mods-available/50-ssh2.ini, in the Additional ini files parsed section in phpinfo but do not see it as installed such as the other options that show as being installed.